# Spring Rest Controller Hierarchy

Tags: spring

I'm trying to create an hierarchy inside of my rest controller without rewrite the completed path, something like:

```
-/api
    -/v1
        -/home
             -/contact
        -/book
    -/v2
        -/home
             -/contact
        -/book
```

This is an example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping( value = "/api")
public class Api {

    @Autowired
    private PRepository pRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/v1", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ...(){
         ...
    }

    // --> I don't want rewrite "/v1"
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ...(){
         ...
    }

    // --> I don't want rewrite "/v1/home"
    @RequestMapping(value = "/contact", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ...(){
         ...
    }

    // --> I don't want rewrite "/v1"
    @RequestMapping(value = "/book", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ...(){
         ...
    }

    // Version 2.0
    @RequestMapping(value = "/v2", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ...(){
         ...
    }

    // --> I don't want rewrite "/v2"
    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ...(){
         ...
    }

    // --> I don't want rewrite "/v2/home"
    @RequestMapping(value = "/contact", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ...(){
         ...
    }

    // --> I don't want rewrite "/v2"
    @RequestMapping(value = "/book", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ...(){
         ...
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

I already read some DOCs, but didn't find anything about it.

> Docs

[ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping.html)

Comment: Honestly I would recomend creating separate controllers for this use case. Then you could have each controller declare the class level request mapping as /api/v1/ and /api/v2/. You don't want a gigantic controller class

Comment: You are right! But... I have some cases which i will need a structure like that :(

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @zero01alpha yes! I want to have a nice project and well elaborated

Comment: No, I meant elaborate on your use case that makes you need a structure like that.